# Disallowed characters in folder names

Tags: cross-platform, directory, filenames

I'm making some software which is cross-OS.

A user is allowed to create profile. They can name it anything, however a folder of the same name is created. So I run into issues of disallowed characters by OS for folder names.

I came across this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words

Per OS, which are disallowed?

Right now I'm assuming that these following **nine** characters are not allowed in folder names for all of Windows, Linux, Mac: `*`, `:`, `?`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `/`, `\` `"`. Is this a correct assumption I can make?

I have Windows only so I was able to verify with this image that this 9 character set is at least true for Win8.1.

[image]

Comment: In Windows are disallowed not only these characters, but also are some reserved names: CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9, CLOCK$. More info: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What is relation between "not allowed characters" and "users can create folders with same name"?

Comment: It's not an option to simply restrict usernames to alphanumeric characters (and hyphens and underscores and perhaps a few other characters that are definitely allowed in folders)?

Comment: @wardk no i cant do that :( My users want the freedom of those other characters.

Comment: @Fumu7 thanks for that question. Please ignore the second part. Just im wondering about the not allowed chars please.

Answer (score 1):

One Unix/Linux/Mac, all of those characters are allowed. It just takes some command line savvy to make it happen:

```
touch foo
cp foo "This is a crazy file name * : ? < \""
```

Then type:

```
ls -l This*
```

Results in:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Sep  7 07:19 This is a crazy file name * : ? < "
```

Comment: Haha funny example. But Im wondering for the average user who's making a folder via GUI :P

Comment: @Noitidart - if your are writing production code for a product that will ship to customers, you'll be surprised what "average users" can generate.

Comment: holy crap i just got vm box oracle and got ubuntu and man i made a folder named `~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=\` is there anyway to include `/` in the name?

Comment: Hi @selbie, on unix and mac, is the only disallowed character `/`?